# Rewrite php file into html extension with parameters

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

how to turn one file into html extension ,i am using following ht-access for removing file name and dot php.

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^adminmobile/ajax/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ /adminmobile/ajax/getorderdetails.php?   order_id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

my question is how to put dot html after 11

thanks for your help

thanks

Comment: the actual is like ----> domain.com/getorderdetails.php?order_id=$1 <------ and i want it look like this
-------> domain.com/1.html <-------

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /getorderdetails\.php\?order_id=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1.html? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^(\d+)\.html$ /getorderdetails.php?order_id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^adminmobile/ajax/([a-z\d-]+)(?:\.html|/)?$ /adminmobile/ajax/getorderdetails.php?order_id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: or-  domain.com/1.html

Comment: No because you replied that you want **the actual is like ----> `domain.com/getorderdetails.php?order_id=$1` <------ and i want it look like this -------> `domain.com/1.html`**. I can make `domain.com/adminmobile/ajax/1.html` work also (see updates).